# Create macro/loop in GAMS

Tags: loops, macros, gams-math

Consider the following set and parameter in GAMS:

```
set i  / 1,3 /
    j  / j1,j2,j3 /;

parameter stock(i,j);
```

Consider I want to put a specific value in the parameter:

```
stock("1","j1") = 10;
stock("3","j3") = 10;
```

Instead of writing that in two lines, can I use macro, $setGlobal, loop (or similar) to first (1) specify which set it should do it for, and (2) secondly only writing the equation in one line?

I can create a subset:

```
set subset_i(i) / 1,3/
    subset_j(j) / j1,j3 /;
```

And then loop through these subset:

```
loop(subset_i,
   loop(subset_j,
      stock(i,j) = 10;
   );
);
```

But then I get the value for each combination:

```
1   j1  10
1   j2  10
1   j3  10
3   j1  10
3   j2  10
3   j3  10
```

I only want:

```
1   j1  10
3   j3  10
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it exactly the diagonal (1-j1; 2-j2), you want to set? Or was that just a random example, and the mapping could also be another one? If it is the diagonal, you can do it like this:

```
set i  / 1,2 /
    j  / j1,j2 /;

parameter stock(i,j);

stock(i,j)$(ord(i)=ord(j)) = 10;

display stock;
```

EDIT (based on the comments/the edited question):

One can also define a more general mapping explicitly, if it is not just about the diagonal. This could be done like this:

```
set i        / 1,  3      /
    j        / j1, j2, j3 /
    map(i,j) / 1.j1, 3.j3 /;

parameter stock(i,j);

stock(map(i,j)) = 10;

display stock;
```

Comment: A little problem: If you have set i / 1,3 / instead of set i / 1,2 /, then I get the result: stock("3"," j2") = 10. However, I want stock("3"," j3") = 10. Is it possible to say that it should insert the value 10, if the value in set i is equal to the value after j in set j? Does it make sense?

Comment: I have changed the text, so it explain it better.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! :-)